Switching from Swashbuckle to Nswag
Looking to make the switch from Swashbuckle to NSwag. Made the necessary changes to my application and have been able to generate the swagger json file through my command line as well.
What I am now looking to do is update my pipeline.
One of the things that has been running on builds is:
dotnet tool install --global Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli so we can then run the swagger to file command.
As far as I can see dotnet tool --global NSwag.AspNetCore.Cli is not a thing. I can't seem to see what the NSwag equivalent is?
